# Discard thousands of uncommitted changes in GIT

Tags: git

I installed GIT on Windows, but without creating any local repository.
When I open GIT I see thousands of unstaged changes, they coincide with all the changes to any file, as if GIT is observing the hard disk root folder C:\

I want GIT to discard any of these changes, but most importantly I want to stop it watching this path.

Which setting should I check?

Comment: Have you started by reading the documentation or reading a book on Git? Try starting there [https://git-scm.com/](https://git-scm.com/)

Comment: It sounds like you said `git init` when you were still in the root folder. Big mistake. You need to fix that immediately, because giving the wrong Git command at this moment can effectively erase your entire hard disk. You need to find the invisible `.git` folder that you have accidentally created, and trash it, _right now_.

Comment: please note: "discard" in git means loosing the changes permanently. Discarding changes in your entire hard disk is very similar to formatting. Please be careful, read a git guide before using the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you by accident download/unpack something containing `.git/` directory in your root folder? (`C:\` for example)

Try running `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` in directory that displays changes to see the "root" of git repository. If in the repository that it returns you see a `.git` directory (hidden by default) you may delete it to stop git from tracking files in the directory tree.

Comment: or, without running any other command, see if C:\.git exists

Comment: The .git folder is in my user folder. Running that command I got `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. I erased it, but what if I moved it in the real folder I wanted to trace?

Comment: You don't have to move/copy it. When you `git init` in working directory it creates `.git` directory that stores your repository (git metadata) - and that's the data specific to this directory with children only. I highly recommend reading some basic guides to git online, probably with interactive tutorials and understand the concept and mechanics of git - working directory, staging area, repository etc. Basically create repository only for directory you want to keep track of. Often `.gitignore` file comes in handy, but you better read about it first. Did that resolve your problem?